# jquery uncheck and check and vise versa checkbox of child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html

```
#This will be generated throught loop

<li class="selector">
    <a>
    <input type="checkbox" value="test" /> test
    </a>
</li>
```

Here is my jquery click event

```
$('.selector').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).find('input').is(':checked')){
    #uncheck the checkbox       
    }else{
    #check the checkbox
    }
});
```

How do I uncheck if checked and check if unchecked

Comment: Side comment, are you sure you want to bind the event on your li tag and not in the input? and use `on('change')` and not `on('click')`

Comment: You can use `.prop()`, you can also check this out [How do I check a checkbox with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: Why do you need jQuery/JS here? It is standard behaviour for a click on a checkbox to uncheck it and vice versa. Why do you have your checkbox inside an anchor tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('input')) {
        $(this).find('input').prop('checked', function () {
            return !this.checked;
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t6LSL/)

Another way

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function (e) {
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', function () {
        return !this.checked;
    });
});
$(document).on('click', '.selector input', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NnQ76/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.selector').on('click', function() {
        var checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
        if($(checkbox).is(':checked')){
             $(checkbox).prop('checked', false);     
        }else{
        #check the checkbox
             $(checkbox).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are trying to do this with JavaScript. If the user clicks directly on the checkbox it will automatically check/uncheck itself, but if you add code to check/uncheck it in JS that would cancel out the default behaviour so in your click handler you'd need to test that the click was elsewhere within the `.selector`.

Anwyay, the [`.prop()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-functionindex--oldPropertyValue) has you covered:

```
$('.selector').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.type === "checkbox") return; // do nothing if checkbox clicked directly
    $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", function(i,v) {
        return !v; // set to opposite of current value
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N4crP/1/

However, if your goal is just to allow clicking on the text "test" to click the box **you don't need JavaScript because that's what a `<label>` element does:**

```
<li class="selector">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="test" /> test
    </label>
</li>
```

As you can see in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/N4crP/2/ - clicking on the text "test" or the checkbox will toggle the current value without any JavaScript.